# Reactive Java Queue With Lazy Fetching

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor

I'm a bit stuck with the idea of implementation of the certain collection. The idea is the following:

- It should work like a simple Queue (poll/offer)
- The API of it should be reactive (either RxJava or Reactor works for me well). This means, I expect the poll method, for example, to look like: `Mono<T> poll();`
- It should lazy fetch the data with the provided loader, if the queue is empty. The loader is also a function returning a batch of next values in a reactive manner
- It should ideally be thread-safe. Not strictly required, but would be nice if I can exclude the race condition when two thread are fetching data after both detecting that queue is empty.

Maybe someone already met such a collection? Or at least something similar? Or at least something that can be used as a base for this one?

Or at least please give me an idea of how to implement such a functionality

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#dispatchworkprocessor). I think Project Reactor has something like it too.

Comment: FYI I don't think we have an equivalent of this `DispatchWorkProcessor` in Reactor